# Scala spark UDF function that takes input and puts it in an Array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create a Scala UDF for Spark, that can be used in Spark SQL. The objective of the function is to accept any column type as input, and put it in an ArrayType, unless the input is already an ArrayType.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
package com.my_namespace.spark.udf

import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession


class GetDatatype extends UDF1[Object, scala.collection.Seq[_]] {
    override def call(inputObject: Object): scala.collection.Seq[_] = {
        if (inputObject.isInstanceOf[scala.collection.Seq[_]]) {
            return inputObject.asInstanceOf[scala.collection.Seq[_]]
        } else {
            return Array(inputObject)
        }
    }
}

val myFunc = new GetDatatype().call _
val myFuncUDF = udf(myFunc)
spark.udf.register("myFuncUDF", myFuncUDF)
```

The data may look like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------+
|create_date|item       |datatype_of_item                                              |item2   |datatype_of_item2              |
+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------+
|2021-06-01 |[item 3, 3]|org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema|string 3|java.lang.String               |
+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------+
```

or this:

```
+-----------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------+
|create_date|item                      |datatype_of_item                           |item2               |datatype_of_item_2                         |
+-----------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------+
|2021-05-01 |[[item 1, 1], [item 2, 2]]|scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef|[string 1, string 2]|scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef|
|2021-06-01 |[[item 3, 3]]             |scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef|[string 3]          |scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef|
+-----------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

The UDF function may be passed contents from item or item2 columns.

However when executing this line:

```
val myFuncUDF = udf(myFunc)
```

I get the following error:

```
scala> val myFuncUDF = udf(myFunc)
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Any is not supported
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.$anonfun$schemaFor$1(ScalaReflection.scala:743)
```

Comment: The probel here is that you can not create an udf with well known result. Spark needs to know the schema of the dataframe. So you would need to wrap both results in one type that should be supported by spark sql.

Answer (score 0):

Spark cannot use UDFs with this return type (Any, oder Object). You could do it without UDF I think:

```
val df = Seq(
 (Seq((1,"a"),(2,"b")),(1,"a"))
).toDF("item","item 2")


def wrapInArray(df:DataFrame,c:String) = if(df.schema(c).dataType.isInstanceOf[ArrayType]) col(c) else array(col(c))

df
 .withColumn("test",wrapInArray(df,"item"))
 .withColumn("test 2",wrapInArray(df,"item 2"))
```

gives the schema

```
root
 |-- item: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- item 2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test 2: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Could this function be registered and be used in Spark SQL? I didn't have any success registering it.